# How do I stop expo remote js debug open on chrome?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

I want to run my react native debugging right on vscode. I change the ports and everything is set. but everytime that I refresh the app. it keeps opening debugging on chrome.

[image]